# How Do I collect The Enderegg?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Ok so I just took 45 minutes to find and kill the enderdragon! BUT! I have the new Xbox 360 disk for minecraft and I hit the egg... AND IT BROKE DX What do I do to collect it?

Comment: Owning XBOX version (never beat it), and have beaten PC version, I would expect the way to harvest it is the same. You build a platform around where the egg rests, and then use a piston to push it. The egg will then become a drop.

Comment: @gnovice, [tag:minecraft] and [tag:minecraft-console] are pretty different games in some places. And where they're similar, their feature lists tend to get out of sync.

Comment: @BillyMailman: This is one aspect where the two [don't appear to differ](http://minecraft360.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Egg).

Comment: @gnovice Then you seem to have an answer worth posting.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty good video for obtaining the ender dragon egg on the XBOX360 version:

*Note: I did not make this video and do not take credit for it.*

Source: I've used this video to collect the ender dragon egg on console version.

Comment: Not bad. Bonus: Video isn't long.